# execute action just before netbeans application closes -- reference netbeans exit window event

Tags: netbeans, java-me, jogl

I am working on a netbeans application with a primary TopComponent containing a rendering canvas:

when I close the application (not the topcomponent) an error is generated and sometimes this results in a process running after the application closes. I have researched some and i have seen that this is an issue with the mtgame engine I am using, but haven't seen any solutions.

If I manually dispose of the canvas before closing the application no error is generated-- I already have this being done via the componentClosed() method that comes with the topcomponent, and that works (only) for X'ing out of the topComponent.

Is there a way to create a class outside the topcomponent (or within) to listen for the event corresponding to the netbeans application closing?

I really appreciate any feedback or suggestions! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this FAQ entry](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqAppLifecycleHooks). Have your module implement [ModuleInstall](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-modules/org/openide/modules/ModuleInstall.html) and override the **close** method.

Comment: Eventually I had to work around the problem, but this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Great to hear that. So maybe you can accept/vote up the answer? :)

Comment: I would twice but I have 11 reputation, I promise I will when I get more rep =)